# Android How do I correctly get the value from a Switch?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, actionlistener

I'm creating a `Android` application which uses a [Switch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html).
I'm trying to listen for changes and get the value when changed.
I have two questions when using switches:

1. What `action listener` do I use?
2. How do I get the the `switch` value?

Comment: I think he must either mean a `ToggleButton` or a `Checkbox`, but the tag `switch-statement` is confusing me, since he may be referring to a `switch(int v){}` for some reason

Comment: @JoxTraex no I have a `Switch` in api 4.0

Comment: @stackoverflow i think it is best answer and show accept as a answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600494/8079868

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
Switch s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.SwitchID);

if (s != null) {
    s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}

/* ... */

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "The Switch is " + (isChecked ? "on" : "off"),
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(isChecked) {
        //do stuff when Switch is ON
    } else {
        //do stuff when Switch if OFF
    }
}
```

Hint: `isChecked` is the new switch value [`true` or `false`] not the old one.

Answer (score 61):

Since it extends from `CompoundButton` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html)), you can use [`setOnCheckedChangeListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener%29)  to listen for changes; use `isChecked()` to get the current state of the button.

Answer (score 12):

```
Switch switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.Switch2);

switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        ...switch on..
                    } else {
                       ...switch off..
                    }
                }
            });
```

i hope this will solve your problem

Comment: It is nice but avoid to use java reserved keyword (switch) as variable name.

Answer (score 2):

I added this in kotlin

```
switchImage.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton: CompoundButton, b: Boolean ->
    if (b) // Do something
    else // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin but in More readable Java Style

```
   videoLoopSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object : CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{
                override fun onCheckedChanged(switch: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {
                    videoPlayer?.apply {
                        setLooping(isChecked)
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
@OnClick({R.id.sw_auto_reload})
void onChangedAutoReload(){
    Switch s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.sw_auto_reload);
    if (s != null) {
        s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                paymentSettingsPresenter.onAutoReload(b);
            }
        });
    }
}
```