# Align Image and Text in the same line in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, switchcompat

I want the image in the left side and the switch text in middle and switch button in right corner. Here is my code

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mobile_data_usage"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_compat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Mobile Data"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        app:showText="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can't understand what you want to do. please explain more in detail.

Comment: What do you wanna ask and you ask who???? Please ask in a right way, at least don't make the reader feel uncomfortable

Comment: You could have asked politely !

Comment: just change the orientation attribute of Linear attribute to 'horizontal'

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mobile_data_usage"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/switch_compat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="Mobile Data"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""
            app:showText="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

try this way make your image size to fix

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.    I think it is what do you want.

```
<LinearLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_mobile_data_usage"
       android:scaleType="fitStart"
       android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:checked="false"
       android:text="Mobile Data"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:textOff=""
       android:textOn=""
       app:showText="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mobile_data_usage"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="switchText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/switch_compat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Mobile Data"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""
            app:showText="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use a linearlayout with android:layout_gravity="center" to align your elements

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="hoizontal" 
>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_mobile_data_usage"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/switch_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mobile Data"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    />

<Switch
   android:id="@+id/switch"
   android:layout:width="wrap_content"
   android:layout:height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="right|top"
   android:checked="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to make a static positioning use in LinearLayout

```
  android:weightSum="100"
```

and in your items

```
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  abdroid:layout:weight="40"
```

if you want that your Item has the size of 40% of width use 40 as Weight, with 33% use 33 as weight and it get´s alligned as you wish :)

It is possible to change the text with the change of the switch. 
[Android How do I correctly get the value from a Switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576307/android-how-do-i-correctly-get-the-value-from-a-switch)

Mfg

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_mobile_data_usage"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Mobile Data" />

<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch_compat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:checked="false"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Try this implementation