# how to display date and time picker when I switch on the button

Tags: java, android

When I switch ON the button, I want 2 text views to appear and if I click each text view it shows open a date and time picker so that I can select them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Android How do I correctly get the value from a Switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576307/android-how-do-i-correctly-get-the-value-from-a-switch)

You can refer this link for checking if switch is on or off and accordingly handle visibility of textview.And you can put your date and time picker onclick of textviews

Do you need even date and time picker code?